# "Join this device to Azure Active Directory" with powerShell

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, windows-10

All

I want to automate the "Join this device to Azure Active Directory", what is the PowerShell command for it, Thanks.

Pls let me know if you know alternative ways to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it's not supported to join your device into AAD with Powershell script.

Please vote up this [user voice post](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20399941-all-powershell-bash-script-azure-ad-join) if you need one.

Comment: Thanks, Allen. Anything else other than "OOBE, bulk enrollment and Autopilot" ?

Comment: @Ming You would like to refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/azureadjoin-plan.